# How to find out whether or not a page is cached?

Tags: caching

I have some serious problems with the performance of my Drupal website and I think that the problem may caused by the fact, that the pages are not cached. How can I find out whether or not a page was cached and if not, how can I find out why the page is not cached?

I am using varnish for my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whether a page is cached**

You can enable [logging](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/tutorial/logging.html) and use `varnishlog`, `varnishstat`, etc. See [Debugging Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/DebuggingVarnish) for a bit more information. There's also a lot of information on Pantheon's [Working with Varnish](http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/425726), I'd highly recommend reading that.

**Why it is not cached**

That's a much bigger, harder question to answer. It's entirely down to your server/application logic. Your server's VCL files, in conjunction with response headers sent from your Drupal application, will determine whether or not a page is cached.

There may be other environmental factors affecting things, but again those would be specific to your server and your sysadmin (or whoever installed/set up the server) should be able to tell you about them.

There's a pretty decent [tutorial](http://linuxdev.dk/articles/varnish-and-drupal-7) available that walks through setting up Varnish with Drupal, I'd recommend reading through that and comparing your own set up to that known-to-be-working one.